# Text EXACTMATCH + other characters

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a list of items that have the main item name plus some others that have customization in them, like below.

[image]

What I'm aiming for is to find how many that are **M01 - Supreme Pizza + OTHER TEXT**. Not the ones with just this M01 - Supreme Pizza.

These are the 2 formulas I tried that gave me something other than an error msg. But the answer is wrong.

=MATCH(A2&"*-*",A2:A17,0)

=MATCH("M01 - Supreme Pizza"&"*-*",A2:A17,0)

[image]

Both these give the result 2. Which is wrong.

I've been mulling over how/if I can use query function for this, but my knowledge with that is zero.

Comment: maybe experiment with `INDEX(reference, MATCH(search_key, range, search_type))` as outlined in [this reference](https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/match-formula-google-sheets/)

Comment: OTOH if you were to replace the "-" after the meal code with "/" for example, you could use `=COUNTIF(A1:A2,"* *")` to find just those with the additional "-" text after the main descriptor so M01 - Supreme Pizza - A15P L10F would become M01/Supreme Pizza - A15P L10F as a simple fix

Comment: Are you using Excel (desktop), Excel Online, or Google Sheets?

Comment: @Rubén Google Sheets

Comment: @ErikTyler The root of my issue is this, so I decided to post this as a separate question because I'm not going beyond this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please only use Excel and Google Sheets tags in the same question when it's about something that involves both apps (both are spreadsheets apps but they only have *some* compatibility)

Comment: @Rubén Noted about this Ruben. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can count values in `A2:A` that start with `M01 - Supreme Pizza` and continue with a space and additional characters like this:

`=countif(A2:A, "M01 - Supreme Pizza *"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @24601 I decided to change the format for the simple solution.

=(INDEX(A2:B17,MATCH("M01"&"*-*",A2:A17,)))